# Angular skipping (not displaying) content when wrapped in [innerHTML]

Tags: angular, angular7, innerhtml

I have data coming from api call, which is in below format:

**Data format**

```
data {
     info:"Disable terminal line access for un-authorized outoging connections using the command<br><br>line [vty/console/aux] <beg line number> <end line number><br> transport output none<br>
}
```

So when I use `[innerHTML]`, it is skipping `< beg line number> < end line number>` but I want this to be displayed. I am currently using Angular 7.

**html code**

```
<ng-template #info let-item="celldata">
    <div [innerHTML]="data.info"></div>
</ng-template>
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by skipping them? Not showing them? And what do those tags mean?

Comment: Yeah not showing them, i think innerHTML assuming them as custom tags and skipping them (not displaying). This is my information coming from backend api call, i want it to be displayed as it is.

Comment: Why display your data as HTML if it is text ?

Comment: The HTML parses thinks they're tags so tries to show them, but obviously fails. Instead of using `<` and `>` try using `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: @Ploppy He mostly likely wants the `<br>` to be parsed to valid html, but not the other ones.

Comment: I cant edit this data as it is coming from backend api call. they want it to be displayed as it is.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren exactly , i want br and other tags to be parsed but not < beg line number> < end line number>

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere Unfortunately I can't think of an easy fix for this. My first instinct would be to use a regex to replace `<` and `>` on all the invalid tags.

Comment: @GiovaniVercauteren regex will also remove for br tags and other tags, so i cant

Comment: Who did downvote? now a days even you provide enough info people are here to just downvote. Any one can give me reason for downVote?

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere That's why you only check for obviously invalid tags. <beg> is an obviously invalid tag.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `<beg line number>` and `<end line number>` are considered as HTML elements by the browser, though these are not the standard elements. You can observe the DOM and see that they are actually created in the DOM. Because browser doesn't know how to render them, they are not visible on the screen. You need to escape the string or use `innerText`. But using `innerText` will not render the `<br>` tags. I think you're out of luck here.

Comment: @31piy Yes, you are right, I tried so many things but no luck yet. Anything included in < > html will consider as custom tag and treat them as html only.

Answer (score 0):

Just escape `<` with `&lt;`

Try like this:

```
 data = {
    info:
      "Disable terminal line access for un-authorized outoging connections using the command<br><br>line [vty/console/aux] &lt;beg line number> &lt;end line number><br> transport output none<br>"
  };
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xezvx3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: As i told you in my question this is backend data, i cant modify this. I have to render this in frontend only.

Comment: Not having access to the backend server code is a thing, not knowing how to modify it in the front end is an other. This is a valid answer to your problem.

Answer (score -3):

```
data {
     info:"Disable terminal line access for un-authorized outoging connections using the command<br><br>line [vty/console/aux] <beg line number> <end line number><br> transport output none<br>
}
```

in the template:

```
<ng-template #info let-item="celldata">
    <div>{{data.info}}</div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This will display other HTML tag as well

Comment: This will not render <br> tags as well. Please read my question and discussion. Thank for your answer by the way.

Comment: working demo its render <br> tags look at this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xezvx3?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: you need to remove [innerHTML] use like that <ng-template #info let-item="celldata">
    <div>{{data.info}}</div>
</ng-template> in expression.